# How to manage s3 bucket for files and app?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cdk

Can someone answer my these two questions plz

1. Do I need to create seprate s3 buckets like one for react app and other for Images and files ?
2. When I deploy my app like this:

   ```
   new s3Deployment.BucketDeployment(this, "deployStaticWebsite", {
    sources: [s3Deployment.Source.asset("../frontEnd/build")],
    destinationBucket: myBucket,
    distribution: distribution,
    // destinationKeyPrefix:"build",
    });
   ```

It replaces all the content of the bucket on every deploy.
what is the best solution to avoid this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you should have a separate bucket for website deployment and data storage. The bucket you use for website will usually be a public one (unless you are using it with cloudfront).